# Using map functions ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I'm trying to compile the following code in ubuntu

```
#include <unordered_map.h>
typedef unsigned int key_type;  // fine, has < , ==, and std::hash
typedef std::map<key_type, some_value_type> my_map;
```

Using this command

```
g++ -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ main.c -o program
```

And i get this error

```
1234@(none:/usr/local/src/testing$ make
g++ -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ main.c -o program
In file included from main.c:5:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/unordered_map.h:33:32: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Here is a locate for map.h

1234@(none):/usr/local/src/testing$ locate map.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_map.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_multimap.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/unordered_map.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/debug/map.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/debug/multimap.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/profile/map.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/profile/multimap.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/profile/impl/profiler_map_to_unordered_map.h

/usr/include/c++/4.5/tr1/unordered_map.h

Additionally i do have other studd in there for mysql, which i will be using, but main is just returning 0;

Comment: Do you want to use `map` or `unordered_map`?

Comment: Why do you include unordered_map but declare a type of map?

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't totally mess up your compiler setup, you shouldn't need to pass that many options. You should be fine to remove `-I/usr/include/ -I/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/`.

```
g++ -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -rdynamic -L/usr/lib/mysql -lmysqlclient \
 -I/usr/include/mysql -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fno-strict-aliasing \
 -DUNIV_LINUX -DUNIV_LINUX main.c -o program
```

Also, since you tweaked your include paths you were able to see an implementation file `unordered_map.h` which should not be included directly. Instead include

```
#include <unordered_map>
// for C++0x
```

or

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
// for C++98
```

In general, the "standard library" headers for C++ do not have a `.h` in their names. The C library headers have it (e.g. `math.h`), but you are provided an additional version with their declarations wrapped properly in the standard namespace. These headers start with `c`, e.g. `cmath`.

Answer (score 1):

Either use `std::unordered_map` and the standard header `<unordered_map>` or use `std::map` and the standard header `<map>`. Don’t mix the two.

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to `-I` into the g++ `bits` directory, but just the include directory directly. This leads me to believe you're using a library that's not compatible with your compiler.

Another option is that code prior to the include of `map` is broken and has mismatched `{` `}` for example.